# How to redirect non-admin/editors from specific pages?

Tags: redirect

I am trying to "hide" one specific category and all posts on that category by redirecting all links to the homepage.

Currently i am using the below on .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 "/coming-soon/" "https://www.website.gr"
Redirect 301 "/category/coming-soon/" "https://www.website.gr"
RedirectMatch 301 ^/coming-soon/.*$ "https://www.website.gr"
```

This partially works with an exception Admins/Editors can't view these pages or preview these posts.

Is there any way i can have these redirect rules to not apply on Admin/Editor users?

Answer (score 0):

Uh Oh. You are using absolutely useless method. Posts, categories(and everything in WP) can be freely accessed via different kind of url combinations,feeds,api and etc (so forget your code/htaccess method).

Instead, use php codes in your active theme's `functions.php`:

```
if (is_category() )
{
    global $cat;
    if ($cat->term_id = 123) 
    {
        if (!current_user_can('install_plugins'))
        {

        }
    }

}
```

replace category id with desired one.